# Shouldn't the audio sample frame count be a power of 2?

Tags: c++, audio, google-nativeclient

I am working on an Audio project with the *Webaudio API* and with Google's *Native Client*. The aim is to set the buffersize of a Webaudio `scriptprocessornode` (Javascript) to the same buffersize of the the Audio object in the PNACL module (C++).

I retrieve the recommended frame count by calling [AudioConfig::RecommendSampleFrameCount](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_dev/cpp/classpp_1_1_audio_config.html#a53611e94bca5d4a5f7acdd3e5285adb9). The problem though is that this funtion doesn't return a power of 2, as I would expect.

```cpp
sampleFrameCount = 
  pp::AudioConfig::RecommendSampleFrameCount(
    this,
    PP_AUDIOSAMPLERATE_44100,
    4096 // I request sample frame count 4096, which should be legal
  );

// Prints 4410 instead of 4096
printf("Sample frame count: %d \n", sampleFrameCount );
```

**I request a sample frame count of 4096. But it recommends me 4410. Why?** Shouldn't a sample frame count / buffersize be a power of two, like the requested 4096?

I followed the [Pepper Audio Sine-Wave tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/coding/audio), and it works like a charm, even with a sample frame count of 4410. Though the problem kicks in when making a `scriptprocessornode` with the buffersize returned by `RecommendSampleFrameCount` in the PNACL Module.
So, this:

```
audioContext.createScriptProcessor(4410, 1, 1);
```

... gives this error (as expected):

> Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'createScriptProcessor' on
>   'AudioContext': buffer size (4410) must be a power of two between 256
>   and 16384.

I think I make a serious conceptual mistake, but I don't know where. Some help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: @kfsone - I understand the confusion, but the number I am dealing with is 4410, not 44100. The number 44100 is used as one of the major standard samplerates; how many samples are read per second. My case is not about samplerate though, it's about buffersize.

Comment: Most likely, the environment is sending you samples at a fixed *time* interval. For instance, with a sample rate of 44100 samples/sec, a buffer size of 4410 means you get a buffer every 100 ms. If, for other reasons, you need to consume samples in buffers of some other size, you will need to move the samples into another set of buffers and manage the leftovers yourself.